# PLSQL: Change Data Capture to get modified records of a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a requirement wherein we have to migrate modified/delta data on a table from Oracle to MongoDb. To do this I have suggested to create Trigger on intended table and insert the Updated/Inserted/Deleted records into logging table and using Java code we will be able to read these modified/delta records and then update the respective collections in MongoDB.

But I have been asked to check the feasibility of Oracle's CDC (Change Data Capture) feature.

I have checked Oracle doc to learn CDC but it takes quite a time. Could you please help me with some steps or any quick tutorial to implement CDC to capture modified data on a table as I have to create a demo.

Also please suggest which will be better from performance point of view to log modified/delta records using trigger or CDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste your time on Change Data Capture.  It's an interesting idea but unfortunately [CDC is desupported in 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/deprecated.htm#UPGRD60083).  And not desupported like the way `IMP` and `EXP` are not supported but will still work forever.  It's been completely removed from the database.  Oracle corporation wants you to pay for Oracle GoldenGate instead.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Heller for your valuable feedback. I shall propose the same to business.